# How to Get the HTTP Post data in C# - FiddlerCore?

Tags: c#, http-post, fiddler, fiddlercore

I am using `Fiddler`.

When I capture a request, it's a `Fiddler.Session` object.

I've been searching this object for hours now, and I can't find the `Request Payload`.

I have searched through all properties, maybe I skipped something, but I can't find it. I searched more `RequestBody` and `RequestHeaders` without success.

This site explains about the `Fiddler` functions:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jul/29/using-fiddlercore-to-capture-http-requests-with-net

So for example I would like to do the following:

```
private void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess)
{
  string payload = sess.??? //Where the property would be the POST data
}
```

Is it possible it's just not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the session parameter is for a POST request you would get the body of the request in the `sess.GetRequestBodyAsString()`;

```
private void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session sess) {
    if (sess == null || sess.oRequest == null || sess.oRequest.headers == null)
        return;

    string reqHeaders = sess.oRequest.headers.ToString(); //request headers        
    var reqBody = sess.GetRequestBodyAsString();//get the Body of the request
}
```